# What's the right english translation of the name of Hit's new technique in the manga?

Tags: dragon-ball-super, japanese-language, dragon-ball-manga

In the Dragon Ball manga, Hit shows a new technique, but it's been translated different in different sources. Some calls it "time shift", and other calls it "time lag". What's the right english translation of the name of Hit's new technique in the manga? Apparently the japanese name is Toki-Zurashi.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are technically correct translations for 時ずらし (Toki Zurashi), as 時 (Toki) means time, and ずらし (zurashi) seems to mean a shift or delay (based on the verb ずらす, to shift or to delay). As the technique [slows an enemy's time](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Time_Lag) to slow the enemy, it stands to reason that either definition would work. Time lag seems like a somewhat odd way of translating it, because the phrase generally means a period of time between one thing happening and the next, but it could mean the time lag between what is happening for Hit and what is happening for the enemy.